# TSNE plot dissapears quickly

Tags: python, matplotlib

i would like to  use t-SNE algorithm on mnist dataset for purpose of dimension reduction, later i want to use  reduced data  for visualization purpose(possible clustering or classification), here is my code :

```
`import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
import  seaborn as sns
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
df =pd.read_csv('mnist_train.csv')
y =df['label']
X =df.drop('label',axis=1)
standardized_X =StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)
data_1000 = standardized_X[0:1000, :]
labels_1000 = y[0:1000]
model =TSNE(n_components=2,random_state=1)
transformed =model.fit_transform(data_1000)
tsne =np.vstack((transformed.T,labels_1000)).T
tsne_df = pd.DataFrame(data = tsne,
     columns =("Dim_1", "Dim_2", "label"))
#print(tsne_df.head())
sns.FacetGrid(tsne_df,hue='label',height=6).map(plt.scatter,'Dim_1','Dim_2')
plt.legend()
plt.show(block=False)
```

but when i run this code,  plt  figure dissapears  quickly, how can i stop  figure from  such action? is it memory problem or  i should add some little line in order to  keep  figure opened? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

i tried a few  experiment and   found solution : set block argument as true  and here is result

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
import  seaborn as sns
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
df =pd.read_csv('mnist_train.csv')
y =df['label']
X =df.drop('label',axis=1)
standardized_X =StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)
data_1000 = standardized_X[0:1000, :]
labels_1000 = y[0:1000]
model =TSNE(n_components=2,random_state=1)
transformed =model.fit_transform(data_1000)
tsne =np.vstack((transformed.T,labels_1000)).T
tsne_df = pd.DataFrame(data = tsne,
     columns =("Dim_1", "Dim_2", "label"))
#print(tsne_df.head())
#fig = plt.figure()
sns.FacetGrid(tsne_df,hue='label',height=6).map(plt.scatter,'Dim_1','Dim_2')
plt.legend()
plt.show(block=True)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gu9E.png)

Comment: The `block` parameter of `plt.show` represents [whether to wait for all figures to be closed before returning](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.show.html).
Additionally, this parameter defaults to `True` when in non-interactive mode. So `plt.show()` should be sufficient.